# CakePHP Pagination order not working

Tags: cakephp

I am using cakephp V2.0.2

I am having trouble with

```
$this->paginate = array(
                "fields" => array(
                    "Player.join_country"
                ),
                "joins" => array(
                    array(
                        "table" => "banner_key_current_ext",
                        "alias" => "BannerKeyCurrentExt",
                        "type" => "inner",
                        "conditions" => "BannerKeyCurrentExt.banner_key_id = BannerKeyCurrent.banner_key_id"
                    ),
                    array(
                        "table" => "players",
                        "alias" => "Player",
                        "type" => "inner",
                        "conditions" => "BannerKeyCurrentExt.identifier = Player.zban_player_id" . $country_condition
                    ),
                    array(
                        "table" => "users",
                        "alias" => "User",
                        "type" => "inner",
                        "conditions" => "BannerKeyCurrent.user_id = User.user_id"
                    ),
                    array(
                        "table" => "tag_links",
                        "alias" => "TagLinks",
                        "type" => "inner",
                        "conditions" => "TagLinks.id = BannerKeyCurrent.user_id AND TagLinks.tag_id = 710"
                    )
                ),
                "conditions" => array(
                    "BannerKeyCurrent.date BETWEEN ? AND ?" => array(
                        $this->request->query["period_from"],
                        $this->request->query["period_to"]
                    ),
                    "BannerKeyCurrent.plan_id" => $brands_plan_map[$this->request->query["brand"]]["plans"],
                    "BannerKeyCurrent.operation_id" => $operation_ids
                ),
                "group" => array( "Player.join_country" ),
                "order" => array(
                    "Player.join_country" => "DESC"
                ),
                "limit" => 999999,
                "maxLimit" => 999999
            );
```

Everything works all fields, joins, group, limits no problem but the ordering simple wont work. Outputting the sql_dump element shows that it is never added to the query.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What does your paginate call look like, and what does `debug($this->modelClass);` output from the controller?

Answer (score 9):

By doing

```
"order" =>  "Player.join_country DESC"
```

Worked for me.

I hope it helps you too.

Comment: thanks man, it works, though weird, with array should work as well according to documentation http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find

Comment: It was working for me when I used it as in the documentation. Then I added a filter condition on the second argument of paginate() and it stopped working, until I did this.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
    "fields" => array(
                "Player.join_country"
            ),
            "joins" => array(
                array(
                    "table" => "b...

$pagedResults = $this->paginate('YourModel');
```

Answer (score 0):

Are there any pagination order by parameters in the url?

Paginator will override any order by in the query with any specified in the url (so the sort column headers work).

If the order parameter refers to an invalid field perhaps cake ignores it after removing your order by from the query ready to add the one in the url.